# Neovim saving yanked text to file with TextYankPost

Tags: neovim, cut-copy-paste

I'm trying to write some functionality in neovim to make it possible to yank + paste between neovim instances. The approach is to intercept yanked text and write it to a temporary file, then remap paste to read from this file.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
function save_yank()
  local text = vim.fn.getreg("*")
  local file = io.open("/tmp/yank", "w")
  file:write(text)
  file:close()
end

function paste_yank()
  local file = io.open("/tmp/yank", "r")

  local text = file:read("*all")
  file:close()
  vim.fn.setreg("0", text, "l")
  vim.cmd("normal! \"0p")
end

vim.api.nvim_command("autocmd TextYankPost * lua save_yank()")
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("n", "<leader>p", ":lua paste_yank()<CR>", {silent = true})
```

My issue is that it seems `save_yank()` is never invoked, which I have verified by putting `print` statements into the function.

Comment: is your autocmd listed in `autocmd_get()`?

Comment: @husB I am not sure how to verify if this is the case.

Comment: @husB to be honest, I am not sure whether using `autocmd TextYankPost` is every the correct approach to begin with here.

Comment: I meant to ask if the output of `echo autocmd_get({'event':'TextYankPost'})` contains your  `save_yank` autocmd. Anyway, for neovim, I believe it is better to use the shared data file (shada).

Answer (score 0):

One may use shada to SHAre DAta between instances of neovim. In particular, the text in the vim registers can be shared, such as the `"`, `+`, and `*` registers.

Using the TextYankPost event, we may write the contents of the registers in one neovim instance to a file (for example `/tmp/yank`) with `:wshada`, and read it in a separate instance with `:rshada`.

```
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"TextYankPost"}, {
  pattern = {"*"},
  command = "wshada /tmp/yank"
})
```

which can also be written in Vimscript as

```
autocmd TextYankPost * wshada /tmp/yank
```

Now,

1. yank some text in one instance
2. switch over to another instance and `:rshada /tmp/yank`
3. paste!

For more, see

- [21.3 Remembering information; ShaDa](https://neovim.io/doc/user/usr_21.html#21.3),
- [Move info from one vim to another](https://neovim.io/doc/user/usr_21.html#_move-info-from-one-vim-to-another), and
- [`:h 'shada'`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/options.html#%27shada%27) to configure which registers or items to read/write into a shared data file.